# How to center input label and input in a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I have this code:

```
<div class="well">
    <form role="form" id="shop-order" method="post" action="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <label for="name">Label</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" name="clientId">
                        $options
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        // possibly other rows...
</div>
```

The result of this code is on this image:

[image]

I don't get how I can center label and input in a row. I want them on one line: middle of label opposite middle of input.

How I can do this? Or probably I my html is wrong and this can be achieved by correct html?

**I am looking for bootstrap method, I understand, that it can be achieved by `line-height`.** I will do it by `line-height` if I wouldn't find bootstrap solution. So I am looking for **bootstrap solution**.

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CVTmF/)

Comment: did u tried line-height and vertical-align:middle?

Comment: It will be "life-hack", I am looking for bootstrap method (well, if I use it...)

Comment: Would be great if you provide a jsfiddle :)

Comment: @merlin 1 moment. Trying to find bootstrap.min.css online

Comment: @merlin I added jsfiddle.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav The jsfiddle you provide doesn't reproduce the layout shown in your image.

Comment: There is only select, isn't it? Thats because of page size. If you make it higher it will display correct result.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Why not use [Horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: @merlin I am using it now as suggested in one of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap provides a **Horizontal Forms** style that seems like what you're looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nv9Q5/1/

Code:

```
<div class="well">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ФИО Клиента</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
              <select class="form-control" name="clientId">
                  <option>one</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it. I am getting [this](http://i.gyazo.com/e0ada2c6f59ffca7e0866d8e6810af44.png). Code is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nv9Q5/)

Comment: You were just missing the classes on the `label` element. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Nv9Q5/1/ Note, you'll need to deal with the md-x / sm-x grid classes to make it work as desired on all screen sizes.

Comment: How I can fix grid classes to make it work properly on all devices? Any tutorial/guide please?

Comment: Yep - the bootstrap documentation/guides are pretty helpful. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Answer (score 0):

Set the css `line-height` of the label to match the height of the input. You'll have to play around to find the right value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: Is there any bootstrap methods?

Comment: If you remove the `pull-right` wrapper from the `label` is it correctly aligned vertically (even though it will now be left aligned)?

Comment: @nicael The answer explains which attribute to add to the label to achieve the desired alignment. The link is supplementary.

Answer (score -1):

Input elements are already inline level element. If you add `text-align:center` to the parent div it will automatically float to the center.

EDITS

If you want to center it vertically, you need to add one more div wrapping the input box

```
<div class="vertically_center">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.vertically_center {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 200px;
   vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I don't need center horizontally, I need center vertically.

Comment: ok. I just update the code. May it help you to center it vertically